# Forecasting using LSTM Model

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I have a dataset with 12 variables (x1, x2, ..., x12) and one target variable (y). Is it possible to perform a forecasting for the target variable (y) over a certain period of time ahead without needing to forecast the values of the predictor variables (x1, x2, ..., x12) for the same period? If it's possible, how can I do this, and could you please provide a Python code example?